# Simulator and Device shows white screen on Debug Mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

I am suffering from the weird issue and not able to get the exact reason of this behaviour. On Objective C project, When I run it on Simulator with Debug or Release mode, it shows couple of Screen correctly but when I click on Login Screen It doesn't show Login screen and it shows blank screen with white background.

I try putting breakpoint on Login screen and ViewDidLoad, ViewWillAppear and all other method calling properly. So there is no issue of connection of Views to ViewController.

However, the same code runs good if I install on Device in Release mode. Same white screen behaviour if I run in debug mode on Device.

Comment: Add a minimum reproducible example

Comment: Perhaps View Debugger could also help.

Comment: @lazarevzubov Nothing in the debugger window.

Comment: @AbhinavMathur I am not sure why and exactly where this issue Occurs. So not able to share code snippet.

Comment: @Deeps It can't be nothing in your view debugger. In your question you stated that you have an initial screen, then you tap a button that is supposed to open the next screen. Instead something happens that results in a white screen. This something means either your initial view controller was removed and the view stack is empty, or the next view controller is unexpectedly blank. Have you tried rotating your view debugger or showing cropped views? What's the view hierarchy on the screen when you see this white thing?